# Gradle - depend on different versions of the same library in different Android modules

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

We've recently updated `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.3` dependency to `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.2` to gain access to some essential new features in the `:app` module.
But it seems like they've changed some very low-level stuff, and one of our features, in a separate module (e.g. `feature`), which uses `androidx.compose.foundation.pager` now crashes the app. At this moment we don't have the time nor resources to rewrite it with a newer version, so we would like to *freeze* the time for this particular feature until we can get to it.
Obviously, we can't just declare `1.4.3` as an `implementation` in `feature` since both `1.4.3` and `1.6.2` classes and functions would have the same signature, and Java Class Loader would have no idea what to use, and Gradle would use the newer one as part of its resolution strategy anyway.
But is it possible to package both `1.4.3` and `1.6.2` in a way that would work around the namespace collision? For example, change `1.4.3` package structure to `legacy.androidx.compose.foundation`. Is this at all viable, or is the best way to deal with this is to just copy-paste `1.4.3` code into `feature`? If it **is** viable, where should I look to learn how to do this?

### Update

I'm making use of a [Gradle Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin to package AAR with the help of [this example](https://github.com/devinmorgan/shadow-plugin-for-aar). Following it, I was able to package `1.4.3` with a different namespace. But I'm facing a different issue - I can't import composable functions from the packaged library.
I can import classes:

```
import com.xxx.legacy.androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerState
```

But not functions:

```
import com.xxx.legacy.androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager
Unresolved reference: HorizontalPager
```

My `feature` `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}
apply<ShadowAarDependenciesPlugin>()

android {
    // ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = compose_version
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            merges += "META-INF/*.kotlin_module"
            excludes += "META-INF/*.version"
        }
    }
}
extensions.getByType(ShadowAarDependenciesPluginExtension::class.java).apply {
    relocations.set(mutableListOf(
        listOf("androidx.compose.foundation", "com.xxx.legacy.androidx.compose.foundation"),
    ))
}
dependencies {

    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))

    add("aarImplementation", "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-util")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
}
```

`build.gradle.kts (buildSrc)`:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}


dependencies {
    implementation("com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:8.1.1")
}
```

What is this issue, why is it happening? How can I fix it?